# Function is declared but its value is never used- importing array from another file but the error is still coming

Tags: javascript, html

```
function filterMovies(language) {
  const languageIndex = filter.indexOf(language);
  if (languageIndex !== -1) {
    filter.splice(languageIndex, 1);
  } else {
    filter.push(language);
  }
  getMovies(filter);
}
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: The function doesn't return a value.

Comment: basically i am having 2 js file in one js file there is array list of movies(languange,name,etc) and iam export that array file to amy 2nd js file and in html i have given onchange function to filter out movies in a category page. So in my 2nd js file where i've imported the array from 1st js and iam writing this function but it is showing its value is never read.

Comment: There's no `return` statement, so it doesn't have a value to read.

Comment: iam calling return statement in html

Comment: Where is it showing that? That doesn't sound like a JavaScript error, maybe a linter warning from your IDE.

Comment: You need to post more code that shows how you're using the function.

Comment: Do you mean `onchange="return filterMovies('xx')"`?  This doesn't need `return`.